# Server-client logging architecture with interprocess communication feature. Do you know the solution?

Tags: c++, logging, ipc

Right now I have:

- a multithreaded **windows service** written in `C++` which use common static libraries as well as dynamic DLLs;
- each thread performs different tasks and produces different errors (DB errors, function invocation errors, etc.). Each thread further will act as a `logger client` (and will send all messages to a `logger server`);
- a **separate thread** which has no body yet, but which **will act as** a `logger server` for handling **all log messages** from the `logger clients`.

I need a good advise of how I should implement following idea into a working solution. The idea is to **add a server-client logging architecture to my multithreaded server** with following requirements (though some parts I need to implement by myself, please consider just the basic idea of `logger client` and `logger server`):

1. there should be a lot of `log clients` (as I already mentioned, the `log client` is just an existed working thread), each should **register an entity with a unique name or/and ID** and following behavior:

   - if the `logger server` is up and is working now, this `log client` starts to send log messages,
   - otherwise (the `logger server` is down), the `log client` endlessly tries to register itself with the `log server` using a small timeout.
2. there should be a `logger server`, with following behavior:

   - `log server` registers all `log clients` with their unique name or/an ID and endlessly checks if there appears a new log client to be registered
   - log server **handles all messages from different** `log clients` and writes to DB, file, etc.
   - there should be an **opportunity to establish connection to the** `log server` from an **external application** (for example, **MySuperThreadViewerProgram** to monitor all thread activity/errors/etc). At the connection, the `log server` should **consider an external application as a one more** `log client`. **It's the most important requirement.**

Summing up, there are **three architecture parts to be implemented**:

1. **Server-client** logger architecture;
2. **Message queue facility** between `log clients` and `log server`. And `log server` **periodically checks** if there any available log clients to be registered;
3. **Inter-process communication** between `log server` and external application, where the latter acts as a new `log client`.

> Please, note, I consider a `logger server` as a kind of **log message router**.

So, the main question is:

> Is there any solution (software framework) which has all described above features (which is **much preferably**) or I should use different libraries for different parts?

If the answer is: "there is no such solution", can you review the choice I made:

- For #1: using **Pantheios** logger framework;
- For #2: using any kind of register-subscribe library with server-client architecture and message-queue support (**update**: [ipc library](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~IPC/)) ;
- For #3: using **Boost.Interprocess** - using SharedMemory.

---

**UPDATE:**

The good example of #2 is [this ipc library](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~IPC/). And may be I was a bit incorrect describing `logger client - logger server` **relations**, but what I really mean is similar to approach, fully described and implemented in **[ipc](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~IPC/)** library: **when one entity (thread) subscribes to another to receive its messages** (or "publish-subscribe" model). 
And I want to use a kind of this technique to implement my logging architecture. But in what way?

---

**UPDATE2:**

OS is Windows. Yeah, I know, under Linux there is a bunch of useful tools and frameworks (D-Bus, Syslog). May be some of you could provide a helpful link to cross-platform library, which can be useful? Maybe there is a **logger framework over D-Bus** under Windows?

---

Any comments are highly appreciated.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What about using the Windows Event Viewer system ? It is quite powerful by itself (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385780.aspx)

Comment: Hmm. Seems very interesting and powerful. I don't know if I could use it, but definitely I will get familiar. Thanks.

Comment: @SirDarius, I read about the **ETW** and unfortunately, it's **not a solution** for me, due to several reasons: `#1` - though I figured out the steps needed to create a fully functional application, there are many unclear and not documented moments in using the framework; `#2` - I want my solution to work both at Windows XP and at Windows Seven, but according to MSDN docs, it is just impossible: I need to write a classic provider for XP and a manifest-based provider for Seven, which is tediously; `#3` - ETW has some critical **limits** for me (f.e. one classic provider - one session), etc.

Comment: ØMQ might also be a viable alternative to the ipc library you mentioned

Comment: @SirDarius, How can I forgot about *Message Queuing*? :( Thanks for reminder. I think, the best solution in my case will be a set of two technologies: **ZeroMQ** (+1 to have an opportunity to work with **pub/sub** and **req/rep** approaches simultaneously) + own protocol implementation using **Google Protocol Buffer**. Thank you very much. P.S. Can you move this comments info a form of answer, so I could upvote it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ØMQ (ZeroMQ) might be a viable alternative to the ipc library you mentioned, as it has a lot of features along the lines of your requirements.

It fully supports the PUB/SUB model, allows you to work between threads, bteween processes and even between machines. It is a client-server architecture, a message queue and works as IPC, too.

Of course, you need a specific way of coding and decoding messages, the protocol buffers are indeed a great idea.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the logging backend pantheios uses (i.e. the log sink: DB, file or whatever) is specified at link-time. The severity of logs going to the backend can be specified at launch-time and with some simple tweaks also during runtime.

If I got you right, then you have one process (let's forget about the external application just for a minute) with multiple worker threads running. Some of these threads should log to a common backend (e.g. DB) and some to another. Because pantheios cannot do this out-of-the-box you'll need to write a custom backend that can route the logs to the correct backend.

If memory consumption is not an issue and you don't need the fastest logging performance, then you might want to look into log4cxx, because it is highly configurable and could possibly spare you from implementing a client-server-architecture with all the synchronization-problems it brings about.

About the external application: If you can guarantee, that it's only one external client, then you could use a pipe mechanism to communicate with the service. The service process would then have a separate thread, which corresponds to your server thread, that opens a named pipe and can also be specified as a log sink so your worker threads can log to it as well as to other log sinks (DB, file etc.).

Comment: Yes, you understood me correct. About **Pantheios**: yes, you right - as soon as I choose this logging framework, I will have to implement a custom back-end (one or even more) or maybe not only a back-end. But the **main goal** is to have a separate thread with a **route** facility. It would be pretty hard to implement (maybe even pointless) this using only Pantheios functionality. For example, that's what needs to be done in a case of **P.**: 1 back-end to redirect all msg to **someclassX**, which provides transport facility (a kind of IPC) to my **threadY**, which is finally a route itself).

Comment: About **log4cxx**: I heard about it, but didn't use it. I believe log4cxx functionality is the same as Pantheios has... And about an external application: I've already tried SharedMemory from Boost::Interprocess and I think it's not the worst case.

Comment: Please, note, I need a server-client architecture, because it's the most elegant and even efficient solution to problem I have. I **do need** a **logger server** (*route server*) which at start receives some settings/options from me/cmd/etc. and will perform different tasks based on these options, including **the most important one**: give all required information to **externally connected** application directly, bypassing of any file or database. Note, that there can be a multiply instances of that app.

Answer (score 0):

There are some syslog servers for win as well. Winsyslog for example is coming from the producers of the famous rsyslog. Once you have syslogd running on win, there are plenty of OS independent syslog clients, such as SysLog4j if you're using Java, or the Syslog handler for the std. python logging.